# Show that $\frac{5}{n}+e^{-n}=O(\frac{1}{n})$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, numerical-methods

**Show that $\frac{5}{n}+e^{-n}=O(\frac{1}{n})$**

I know that $e^n>n, (n\geq 0)$, with which $e^{-n}<\frac{1}{n}$ and so $\frac{5}{n}+e^{-n}<\frac{5}{n}+\frac{1}{n}=6\frac{1}{n}$, then $\frac{5}{n}+e^{-n}=O(\frac{1}{n})$. Is this argument right? Thank you very much.

Comment: It seems correct to me, since you have that $\frac{5}{n}+e^{-n}<C\frac{1}{n}$, for $n\geq n_0$, where $C=6$ and $n_0=0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\frac{\frac5n+e^{-n}}{\frac1n}=\frac{5e^n+n}{e^n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}5$$

Comment: Explain a little more please, what conclusion is reached in this case?

Comment: @user482152 That there exists a contant $\;C\;$ s.t. $$\left|\frac5x+e^{-n}\right|\le C\left|\frac1n\right|$$which is the definition of big O in your case.